# Changing Iphone/Android Wifi into monitor mode

Tags: android, iphone, wifi, monitor

does anyone knows how to change  Iphone and Androids WIFI into a monitor mode?
 I want to write an App that collects all the  Probe Request Frames from all WIFI-Devices to analyse them.

Answer (score 1):

See
http://bcmon.blogspot.ru/

They say it is possible only on some phone models.